# Appropriate Python error type for argument type mismatches

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I am looking for the equivalent of PHPs InvalidArgumentException to use in case a function gets an argument that has an incorrect type. I'm working with Python 3. (And I am quite new to Python.)

[`ValueError` documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) states "argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value", so is not the right one to use here.

[`TypeError` documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError) states "Raised when an operation or function is applied to an object of inappropriate type", and thus also does not seem applicable.

What is the correct error type to use in my case?

Comment: Why do you think TypeError is no good?

Comment: What sort of functions are you writing that *need* type checking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would go with `TypeError` in your case.

*A function is applied to an object of inappropriate type* can be understood as passing an argument of the wrong type (the function is *applied* to its arguments).

For instance, `len(42)` raises `TypeError`, because `len()` cannot be applied to a number.

Comment: Ah yes. The word object threw my off, as I'm not used to arguments always being objects, as I guess is the case in Python.

Comment: @Jeroen, indeed, [everything is an object in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865911/is-everything-an-object-in-python-like-ruby).

Answer (score 2):

```
int([])
#>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
#>>>   File "<string>", line 88, in <module>
#>>>   File "", line 1, in <module>
#>>> TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

Is that not the sort of error you're looking for?

Note that type-checking is ill-advised since it'll throw errors anyway if it doesn't support the wanted interface and *not* checking allows duck-typing.

Comment: I understand that in the Python community, duck-typing is generally accepted and type checking frowned upon. I generally dislike duck-typing, as it is not good for error locality, and is less strict. That is however personal preference, both approaches have their merits.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick way to check if the type is not matching or matches:

```
def my_function(my_word: str):
    if type(my_word) != str:
        raise Exception("Whatever exception you want to raise!")
    pass
```