# Can hasattr work on a Module?

Tags: python

I'm adding dynamically attribute to a module, before using it I want to verify that the added attribute exist (in the module).

hasattr signature is:

```
hasattr(object, name)
```

module is not an object, so how can I verify the existence of the added attribute ?

Comment: Python module **is** an object

Comment: In python everything is an object)

Comment: Why didn't you try it before asking?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need some key word for the module name. If for example my module is called 'MyModule' and I want to see if attribute 'MyAttribute' is exist, I want NOT to check it by hasattr('MyModule', 'MyAttribute') but by some key word that will recognize the module name - hasattr(key word, 'MyAttribute').

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A Python module **is** an object. `hasattr()` works just fine on that.

Demo:

```
>>> import os
>>> type(os)
<type 'module'>
>>> os
<module 'os' from '/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>
>>> hasattr(os, 'sep')
True
>>> hasattr(os, 'foobar')
False
```

If you have a string with the module *name*, then you can look up the module object in the [`sys.modules` mapping](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.modules):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules['os']
<module 'os' from '/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>
 >>> hasattr(sys.modules['os'], 'sep')
True
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I need some key word for the module name.

If for example my module is called 'MyModule' and I want to see if attribute 'MyAttribute' is exist, I want NOT to check it by hasattr('MyModule', 'MyAttribute') but by some key word that will recognize the module name - hasattr(key word, 'MyAttribute').

Comment: @EitanG: You can look up modules by name in the `sys.modules` mapping: `hasattr(sys.modules[modulename], 'MyAttribute')`.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import os
>>> hasattr(os, 'path')
True
>>>
```

As you seen `hasattr` works on modules (everything is an object in python, including functions and modules).

Answer (score 1):

Why not?

```
>>> import sys

>>> sys.modules['sys']
<module 'sys' (built-in)>

>>> type(sys.modules['sys'])
<type 'module'>

>>> hasattr(sys, 'argv')
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it **is** an object. ***Everything in python is an object***. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865911/is-everything-an-object-in-python-like-ruby/866083#866083) question as well.

```
    >>>import os
    >>>issubclass(type(os), object)
    True
    >>>hasattr(os, 'kill')
    True
    >>>
```