# python: can't work out why len function() is behaving not as expected

Tags: python

i have been working on a python tutorial and have come across a problem which i simply cannot work out. google has not turned up anything specific and after a few hours away and much trial and error i still cannot work it out.

anyway, the below code is a simplified version of the tutorial. it works fine and prints out that my file is 17 bytes long:

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, file1 = argv

file_open = open(file1)
file_read = file_open.read()

print "the file is %s bytes long" % len(file_read)
```

then the tutorial asks to merge lines 6 and 7 into a single line. if i do it like this it works:

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, file1 = argv

file_read = open(file1).read()

print "the file is %s bytes long" % len(file_read)
```

but, if i do it like like this then i get an error message which says `TypeError: object of type 'file' has no len()`:

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, file1 = argv

file_read = open(file1, "r+")

print "the file is %s bytes long" % len(file_read)
```

my problem is i cannot work out why that error message is occurring when i am adding the "r+" to make sure the open file is read. ( although, is it true that read is default anyway so maybe even adding the r+ is unnecessary )

any help would be much appreciated. many thanks :)

Comment: The last bit of code, `file_read` is a file-object.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. what i can't work out though is why this matters? i am complete beginner and i cannot see why i am getting the error if the file can be read?

Answer (score 3):

I think you forgot the `.read()` in:

```
file_read = open(file1, "r+")
```

so `file_read` is a file object. Try with:

```
file_read = open(file1, "r+").read()
```

and it will return a string as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether you open it in `r` mode, `r+` mode, or any other mode, opening a file with the [`open`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#open) built-in returns a [file object](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects):

```
>>> open('test.txt', 'r+')
<open file 'test.txt', mode 'r+' at 0x013D9910>
>>> type(open('test.txt', 'r+'))
<type 'file'>
>>>
```

Moreover, you cannot use the `len` built-in on this object:

```
>>> len(open('test.txt', 'r+'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'file' has no len()
>>>
```

This is because, technically, a file object has no length.  It is just a pointer to a certain file.

---

As you noted, the way to fix the problem is to first invoke the file object's [`read`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) method.  Doing so will return the file's contents as a string, which you can then use `len` on:

```
>>> open('test.txt', 'r+').read()
'hello world'
>>> len(open('test.txt', 'r+').read())
11
>>>
```

Comment: hi, thank you for for taking the time to reply. i have been looking into what objects are and as far as i can tell everything is an object. i mean, why does adding the .read() work and why does just adding +r within the parameter break the code? what is python thinking to give me this error? thanks again. :)

Comment: @user2804628 - Well, as I said, using `open` returns a file object.  At this point, you have not read-in the file's contents.  Instead, you have just established a "connection" to the file.  Invoking the `read` method however reads-in the file's contents and puts them in a string.  You cannot use `len` on the file object because it has no length.  It is just a pointer to the file.  You can however use `len` on the string returned by the `read` method.

Comment: @user2804628 - And yes, [everything in Python is an object](http://stackoverflow.com/a/865963/2555451). :)

Answer (score 0):

In the second example you are trying to find the length of the file pointer, which is not possible. SO add:

```
file_read.read()
```

instead of just file_read

Answer (score 0):

When using [len](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len), it only accepts objects with a certain `type` if you're passing in an object with `<type 'file'>` it will throw an exception.

```
>>> f = open('/some/file/path', 'r+')
>>> type(f)
<type 'file'>
>>> 
>>> type(f.read()) # the read method returns an object with type 'str'
<type 'str'>
```

Here `f.read()` returns a `str` object.