# hasattr on class names

Tags: python, hasattr

[hasattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr) documentation says that it takes an object and an attribute name and lets you know if that attribute exists on that object.

I have discovered that it seems to work on class names too (i.e. not an instance object).

Something like:

```
class A:
    def Attr1(self):
        pass

> hasattr(A, 'Attr1')
True
>
```

I would like to use this to make some test code easier to write, but don't want to be bitten later in case this is a side effect of the implementation and not really intended.

<sub>Please don't ask to see the test code to see if I can do something else, as that is not really the question.</sub>

Is there any official python stance on this? I presume the object referred to, in the documentation is talking about an instance object.

I tried googling (and looking at some questions in StackOverflow), but didn't seem to find anything.

Comment: *"I presume the object referred to, in the documentation is talking about an instance object"* - no, any object, including the class itself.

Comment: That's normal. Remember that `instance.method(stuff ...)` is in fact syntactic sugar for `Class.method(instance, stuff ...)`, i.e. those methods are in fact attributes of the class.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: That is great! Is there any reference for that. Seems a bit strange to me :-)

Comment: @ProgrammerPerson if the documentation meant a specific kind of object, it would say that. *Everything in Python is an object*; you can run `hasattr` on anything.

Comment: @tobias_k: I understand that methods are attributes. What I am worried about is using `hasattr(A, blah)`, instead of `hasattr(x, blah)` where `x = A()`.

Comment: Classes *are* instance objects; they are instances of `type` (or whatever the metaclass of the class is).

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I am not disputing :-). Just want a reference (even for the sentence that everything is an object...) Asyou can tell, I am new to python...

Comment: @ProgrammerPerson oh, come on; first Google hit for *"python everything is an object"*: http://stackoverflow.com/q/865911/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Come on :-). Everything is an object has multiple interpretations. Like 5 is an object. Do you include: Type T is an object? chepner's comment comes close to an answer for that.

Comment: btw, thanks everyone! I will wait a few hours before accepting an answer.

Comment: @ProgrammerPerson there's no *"interpretation"* here. `5` is an `int` object. `int` is a `type` object. Functions, classes, modules; all are objects of various kinds. Python is *wholly object-oriented*, it doesn't have the "primitive" data types of e.g. Java.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: There is, for someone new to python coming from other languages. Hence the confusion. I can understand saying every thing that can be passed around (including functions) are objects. But class names could still be considered non-objects. Anyway, seems like my question has been answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that it works on a `class` in addition to an instance is intentional.  In fact, `hasattr` should work on *any* object that you pass to it.  Basically, it does something like this:

```
def hasattr(obj, attribute):
    try:
        getattr(obj, attribute)
    except:
        return False
    return True
```

You can rely on that and not be afraid of getting bit by a change later.  Note, there is some discussion on python-dev about [`hasattr` being broken by design](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-August/103178.html).  The gist of it is that `hasattr` catches *any* exception which can be misleading.

---

Note that, in python classes are themselves instances of `type`.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...   pass
... 
>>> type(Foo)
<type 'type'>
```

so everything is an instance of *something*<sup>1</sup>.

<sup><sup>1</sup>`type` is an instance of itself which is something that would be impossible to do in pure python...</sup>

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't realize `hasattr()` was broken like that.

Comment: @Kevin -- Yep.  I've even seen people mention that it'll catch crazy stuff like `StopIteration` and `SystemExit` -- But I'm not sure if that's true.  In any event, I've seen a number of people writing their own versions... `return getattr(obj, attr, sentinel) is not sentinel`

Comment: I just looked into this and it's [apparently fixed in 3.2](https://bugs.python.org/issue9666)... no word on whether 2.7 users are out of luck.

Comment: Your second paragraph answers it for me.

Answer (score 3):

I do not have a reference on the "official Python stance" at hand, but this is perfectly normal and intentional. Remember that

```
instance_of_SomeClass.some_method(parameters, ...)
```

is in fact syntactic sugar for

```
SomeClass.some_method(instance_of_SomeClass, parameters, ...)
```

i.e. those methods are in fact *attributes of the class* and thus can be tested with `hasattr`.

Comment: Good explanation. Gives the answer as to why methods are attributes of a class. That is, class attributes.

Answer (score 1):

> Just want a reference (even for the sentence that everything is an object...)

I recommend you to read this chapter (or the whole book if you have the time):

http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/everything_is_an_object.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I got +15 rep, so +1 for you :)