# What is being called when doing int() and float()?

Tags: python, constructor, int

I understand that when I do:

```
>>> int(4.0)
>>> int('10')
```

The `__init__()` method from the class of the argument (in the example, `float` and `str`, respectively), will be called.

I wonder what will happen if I do `int()`, I mean, without any argument. It wont call `__int__()` from class `NoneType`, because it doesn't implement that method.

What will happen?

Also, does this mean I can only directly call the constructor of class `int` if the argument is an `int`?

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you think `int()` calls `__init__` on anything? (and technically speaking, `str` and `int` don't even have `__init__` methods).

Comment: Image the argument to `int` has a default value of 0: `def __new__(cls, value=0)`.

Comment: Especially why you think it would call it on the *argument*, rather than on the `int` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in python [everything is an object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/865963/3220135), so when you call:

`x = int(y)` then constructor `int.__new__(cls, value=y)` is called.

this returns an int object and assigns it to `x`.

`x` may have a method bound to it: `x.__init__()` to control it's setup after creation, but creating the object in the first place is handled by the method `__new__()` of the base class.

If you provide no value to `int()`, the default value from the constructor call:

`int.__new__(int, value=0)` is substituted. Then as you mentioned, `int` has no `__init__` method to modify it's setup after creation..

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Makes sense.