# In python what does it mean by everything is an object

Tags: python

I have started learning about python, reading some tutorials, and i have seen the sentence that `Everything is an object in Python`, what does it actually mean?

Comment: It means that everything from an int to a string to a function to a class is an object with methods and "constuctors" and the whole shebang. try help(int) in an interpreter. that whole (almost) list is functions you can run. for example, `x.__float__()` is the same as `float(x)`

Comment: Every single thing has a state and behavior.

Answer (score 9):

It means that almost everything that you use:

1. is an instance of a class
2. has attributes

I say "almost" because this doesn't hold for keywords (such as `for`, `if`, `def` etc).

**Everything is an instance of a class**

When you define a variable, Python creates a pointer to an object in memory. This object is an instance of a class. You can use the function `type()` to see the class your variable belongs to.

```py
>>> x = 100
>>> type(x)
int
```

`int` is the class itself - not a string representing it. Indeed, you could use this class to create other integers.
You could think of classes as "factories" that create new objects of the type that they describe.

```py
>>> # the class int is taking a string as a parameter and creating an integer
>>> int('123')
123
```

Going one step further, since we said that "everything is an object", classes must also be objects. But, if every object is an instance of a class, then also the classes must be an instance of some classes.

It turns out that in Python there is a metaclass `type` of which all classes are instances. You can think of it as a sort of "universal" factory that creates factories (our classes).

```py
>>> type(int)
type
```

**Everything has attributes**

To see the attribute of an object you can use the `dir` function:

```py
dir(x)
```

Attributes can be methods or simply store some data. For instance:

```py
>>> import os
>>> 
>>> os.sep  # returns the string (some data) that shows the default path separator of your operating system
'/'
```

Finally, remember that you can change attributes

```py
os.sep = '\\' # change to Window path separator
```

or create new ones:

```py
os.pc_owner = 'hb'
```

Answer (score 2):

It was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865911/is-everything-an-object-in-python-like-ruby) !

> Everything in Python is an object, and almost everything has
>   attributes and methods. All functions have a built-in attribute
>   **doc**, which returns the doc string defined in the function's source code. The sys module is an object which has (among other things) an
>   attribute called path. And so forth.

Answer (score 1):

There are no primitive data types as you would find in Java or C++. For example try the following:

```
a = 5
dir(a)
```

You will get a rather large list of built in methods that you would not expect to get from "just" an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Python is Pure **Object Oriented language**.
Python treats everything happening around it as the Objects. But Wait,
There are other primitive, non-primitive and special structured data types.
You Can check the datatype of your variable using built-in function of python called

```
type(variable_name) # will check datatype of variable.

dir(variable_name) # will check the functionality of particular object
```