# Python bindable entities?

Tags: python, bindable

I saw that, in the book,
Programming Language Design Concepts by John Wiley, 2004,
there is a definition for bindables:

"A bindable entity is one that may be bound to an identifier. Programming languages vary in the kinds of entity that are bindable:

• C’s bindable entities are types, variables, and function procedures.

• JAVA’s bindable entities are values, local variables, instance and class
variables, methods, classes, and packages.

• ADA’s bindable entities include types, values, variables, procedures, exceptions, packages, and tasks."

I'm curious, which bindable entities are in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any object has an identifier in Python and everything is a object. `id()` [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) would give an identier for any object:

```
id(1)
a = 1  
id(a)
import re
id(re)
foo = lambda x: x
id(foo)
```

Update: something which is not on object are the statements, but one would not expect them to be (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865911/is-everything-an-object-in-python-like-ruby)):

```
id(if)
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Thanks Evgeny, I understand how this applies to my question.