# In python 3 when can type() return anything other than a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I was going through the source code for the `copy` library and I found this:

```
cls = type(x)

copier = _copy_dispatch.get(cls)
if copier:
    return copier(x)

try:
    issc = issubclass(cls, type)
except TypeError: # cls is not a class
    issc = False
```

The important lines being `cls = type(x)` and `except TypeError: # cls is not a class`. (I left in the lines inbetween in case they help). The `except` clause leads me to believe that there is some `x` for which `type(x)` would not return a class, however I can not think of an example where this would be the case. (I tried adding a `print` statement to the clause and seeing if I could trigger it to no avail). Could you give me an example where `type()` does not return a class?

Comment: [Everything is an object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865911/is-everything-an-object-in-python-like-ruby). Therefore, everything's type is a class.

Comment: Even seeing the [bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue11480) that lead to this change and the [commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/5c1c3b4f197c57952760be37d77d73669284a607) that introduced this code, it still doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 9):

If you're asking about the check in `copy.copy`, that's actually not necessary. It's a longstanding bug, but a trivially unimportant one that nobody bothered to fix for years. But, coincidentally, it was [fixed just 11 days ago](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/2708578736d1aa15685495e9b94b827a8e185a8c) as part of [issue 11572](https://bugs.python.org/issue11572), an umbrella bug that aims to finish code coverage of the `copy.py` module for 3.8.

The root cause here goes back to a real issue that existed in Python 2.2 until somewhere later in the 2.x branch (I'm guessing until 2.5, inclusive, but that's a guess)—but the fix wasn't added until 3.4, long after the problem had ceased to exist.

---

This check does not exist in Python 2.x. As hunted down by user2357112, it was added as part of a fix for [issue 11480](https://bugs.python.org/issue11480) in Python 3.4. `copy.copy` on a class with a custom metaclass *was* broken, and a fix was necessary, which was copied from `copy.deepcopy`, but included a change that wasn't needed anymore. Which was later removed from `deepcopy`, but sat around in `copy` until this month.

---

As found by tripleee, the original bug was [#502085](https://bugs.python.org/issue502085).

In fact, in 2.2, it was not only *possible* to have `issubclass(type(x), type)` raise a `TypeError`, it was actually happening in the wild.

In Python 2.1 and earlier (before [PEP 252](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0252/), extension types could basically stick anything they wanted in their type slot. In 2.2+, this would break `isinstance` and `issubclass`. They were made to raise a `TypeError` instead of segfaulting, and that was good enough, because who's ever going to stick a non-type in a type slot, right? Well, the original version of `boost::python` did exactly that for you.

The next version didn't cause that problem, presumably not everyone upgraded right away (it required rewriting part of your code, it couldn't generate modules compatible with Python 2.1, and a 2MB download, seriously? do you think I'm on 224Kbps dual-ISDN or something?), so those exceptions were a real thing to worry about for a while.

(This is only tangentially related to old- vs. new-style classes—extension types were effectively always "new-style" even before that was a thing, and I'm pretty sure the check for their type being a type was added before 3.0.)

---

While we're at it, technically, the word `class` is ambiguous in the Python docs. Sometimes a `class` is something created by executing a `class` statement or by calling the `type` constructor (or calling a subclass of `type`). Sometimes a `class` is an instance of `type` or a subclass of `type`, in which case builtin types *are* classes.

By the former definition, `x = 1` is an example where `type(x)` is not a class. But by the latter definition, it is—and that's clearly the definition used by [`issubclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#issubclass). So, this is mostly irrelevant, unless you're looking for a gotcha question to annoy someone.

Comment: `type(x)` won't return a `classobj` on Python 2; `x.__class__` would do that, but `type(x)` will return `types.InstanceType` for old-style instances.

Comment: @user2357112 No, it will return `types.InstanceType` (aka `instance`) for an _instance_ of a class, but `classobj` (aka `types.ClassType`) for a class. Also, for an instance, `x.__class__` is the class itself, not `classobj` (and `x.__class__` on a class is just an AttributeError). [repl.it demo](https://repl.it/repls/TrimNervousQuadrants)

Comment: I think we're getting `classobj` and "a `classobj`" mixed up here.

Comment: Your answer currently says "In Python 2.x, type(x) might return a class that's a `classobj` rather than a `type`." As I read it, this is saying that `type` might return an old-style class. It won't; for instances of old-style classes, `type` will return `types.InstanceType` rather than their old-style class. This is what I was trying to communicate with my previous comment.

Comment: FWIW "SF 502085" appears to refer to https://bugs.python.org/issue502085 ... Maybe this bug tracker was hosted on Source Forge at the time?

Comment: @tripleee Ah, it's not even for old-style classes, but for pre-2.2 extension types… Nice find; I'll update the answer.