# Python predict_proba

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a question on a classification problem in machine learning using the `log_loss` function in `scikit-learn`.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
classifier = RandomForestClassifier()
classifier.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
soft = classifier.predict_proba(Xtest)[:,1]
log_loss = log_loss(ytest, soft)
```

I would to compute the log loss but an error appears :

```
'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

I think that this problem may come from the fact that there is some 0 in the vector soft. But I do know to solve this problem ?

```
s = 0
for x in soft : 
    if x == 0 : 
        s+=1
print(s)
>> 17729
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show the full stack trace of error and how `log_loss` is imported?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears as if your issue here is not really with the log_loss inputs, but just to do with your variable naming.  [Everything in python is an object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/865963/1643946) and so in the line:

```
log_loss = log_loss(ytest, soft)
```

you assigned the answer, a number (of type `numpy.float64`), to the token `log_loss`.  So your variable shadows the function. Then, subsequent calls, as if it were a function, fail.

```
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
print(log_loss)
>>> <function log_loss at 0x7f9f692db1b8>

log_loss = log_loss(ytest, soft)
print(log_loss)
>>> 0.11895972559889094
log_loss = log_loss(ytest, soft)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-b423b2324b92> in <module>()
----> 1 log_loss = log_loss(ytest, soft)

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

Simplest resolution is not to call your variable `log_loss`, but more generally you might find some level of namespacing helps, e.g. instead of

```
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
...
loss = log_loss(ytest, soft)
```

you could use

```
from sklearn import metrics
...
loss = metrics.log_loss(ytest, soft)
```

Comment: thanks but downvote? is your problem solved or do you need further help to get there?