# Are there objects that cannot be coerced into a string in python?

Tags: python

In Python, can any object be coerced into a string unless its `__str__` method is overloaded to raise an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in [Python is an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865911/is-everything-an-object-in-python-like-ruby#865963).

The type object has a method for string coercion as you’ve noted. If some object did not have this method defined, it would not be an object. This contradicts the first statement. QED.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any Python object can be converted to a `str`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

> Some operations are supported by several object types; in particular, practically all objects can be compared, tested for truth value, and converted to a string (with the `repr()` function or the slightly different `str()` function). The latter function is implicitly used when an object is written by the `print()` function.