# Calling a function which belongs to a class in python

Tags: python

When I create a function in python for example

```
def foo():
  pass
```

And when I type `print(type(foo))` it returns `class ‘function’`,

so my question is if every function we create belongs to class ‘function’ why we print `foo()` instead of `function.foo()` to call this function?

Because if I create a class and add a method to call this method I would write `classname.method()`

Comment: I suggest that you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/865963/866527) answer and the article there.

Comment: The type is distinct from the namespace; you don't need `str."text"` either (though `str("text")` is possible if you really want to).

Answer (score 1):

`foo` has *type* `function`; it is not an *attribute* of the `function` class.

More precisely, `foo` is a name in the global scope that is bound to a value of type `function`, rather than being a name in the in the namespace of the `function` class.