# Pass 'value type' on stack by ref - memory footprint

Tags: c#, .net, memory

What happens in memory when we pass a value type - which has been stored on the stack - by reference?

A temp value/pointer must be created somewhere to change the origninal value when the method completes. Could someone please explain or point me to the answer - lots of stuff on memory but none seem to answer this. ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a method like this:

```
static void Increment(ref int value)
{
   value = value + 1;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
int value = 5;
Increment(ref value);
```

then what happens is that, instead of the value 5 being pushed on the stack, the location of the variable `value` is pushed on the stack. I.e. the contents of `value` are changed directly by `Increment` and not after the method completes.

Here's the IL of the method and the method call respectively:

```
.method private hidebysig static void Increment(int32& 'value') cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldarg.0 
    L_0002: ldarg.0 
    L_0003: ldind.i4         // loads the value at the location of 'value'
    L_0004: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0005: add 
    L_0006: stind.i4         // stores the result at the location of 'value'
    L_0007: ret 
}

.method private hidebysig static void Main() cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 9
    .locals init ([0] int32 value) //   <-- only one variable declared
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldc.i4.5
    L_0002: stloc.0 
    L_0003: ldloca.s 'value'   // call Increment with the location of 'value'
    L_0005: call void Program::Increment(int32&)
    L_000a: ret 
}
```

Comment: Thanks - So a pointer is create on the stack to values' location on the stack... cool! I wish the call stack would show exactly what is going on in memory. Should probably get a myself a memory profiler.

Comment: If you're interested in what's going on behind the scenes it's always worth having a look at the IL generated by the compiler. You can use .NET Reflector to disassemble your assemblies.

Comment: I do use reflector often but don't fully understand IL call just yet. I must admit I didn't think to check the IL here for some reason... Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for some details on Boxing and Unboxing, which are the terms used to describe treating a value type as a reference type.

There's lots of articles out there that describe the process, I'll try to find some decent ones--[but here's one for starters](http://www.csharphelp.com/archives/archive100.html).

Comment: Here's an answer to "why is boxing and unboxing bad?" which provides some insight into the pointer handling and performance hit of boxing/unboxing value types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055/what-is-boxing-and-unboxing-and-why-is-it-bad/25324#25324