# Unity3D localscale issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, scale

The following code:

```
Debug.LogWarning("updating scale fix, scalefactor: "+scaleFactor+" - Current scale is: "+cell.transform.localScale.x);
cell.transform.localScale.Set (scaleFactor,scaleFactor,scaleFactor);
Debug.LogWarning("Scale after fix: " + cell.transform.localScale.x);
```

Produces the following output:

```
updating scale fix, scalefactor: 0.9 - Current scale is 0.8921105
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)

Scale after fix: 0.8921105
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)
```

Any ideas? I would just assume that since these things are happening right after each other, the scale should be updated. Or does that happen after a frame has completed?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

localScale is a property so it returns a copy of the real localScale (Vector3 is a struct)
Try `cell.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (scaleFactor, scaleFactor, scaleFactor);`
or `cell.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * scaleFactor;`

Comment: Spot on. [A little more background reading for OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251608/are-structs-pass-by-value).

Comment: This worked, thanks. One question I had though was that the .Set(x,y,x) was assumed to be used for this purpose. And yet, I do not see any documentation on it.

Comment: But how to scale it from one point e.g. From Left to right? Is it possible to set pivot position programatically?

Comment: Yes, you can change `transform.position` and `transform.localPosition`.