# Unity Color Extension Method not Affecting Color

Tags: unity-game-engine, extension-methods

I want to change the alpha value of an existing color. However, I cannot directly edit the color.

When I try something like this:

```
gui.color.a = 0;
```

I get the following error:

> Error: Cannot modify the return value of 'UnityEngine.GUITexture.color'
>   because it is not a variable.

But if I copy the variable I am able to edit the alpha value.

```
Color tempColor = gui.color;
tempColor .a = .25f;
gui.color = tmpclr;
```

Why is this? Why is the new instance of the Color not throwing the same error?

Additionally, I thought that because I had to do this often I would write a little extension method like this:

```
private static Color tempColor;
public static void SetAlpha(this Color color, float alpha)
{
    tempColor = color;
    tempColor.a = alpha;
    color = tempColor;
}
```

But to my surprise this compiled but didn't change the alpha value at all. Can anyone explain why this might not be working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#, structs are [passed by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251608/are-structs-pass-by-value).

When you get `gui.color`, you're getting a *copy* of the `GUITexture`'s color; changes made to the copy do not alter the original.

The following doesn't work, because you're modifying and discarding a copy:

```
gui.color.a = 0;
```

The following does work, because you're getting a copy, modifying it, and passing it back:

```
Color tempColor = gui.color;
tempColor.a = .25f;
gui.color = tmpclr;
```

An extension method for `Color` fails for the same reason: the extension method will be called on the copy, not the original. You could write an extension method for `GUITexture`, instead:

```
public static void SetAlpha(this GUITexture self, float alpha) {
    Color tempColor = self.color;
    tempColor.a = alpha;
    self.color = tempColor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error message, because by using c# as scripting language your are getting a struct as the color attribute. This means you are getting a copy of the color variable:

```
gui.color // this is a struct and also a copy of the original color attribute
```

So the compiler warns you about making an unnecessary change to a copy.

Have a look at this question:
[Cannot modify the return value error c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747654/cannot-modify-the-return-value-error-c-sharp)