# is C# get property return by value or reference

Tags: c#, properties, godot

I wonder what gets returned using the get property for C# on an object, is it a reference or it is a copy of what that property is assigned to?

From my understanding it's actually returning a copy instead of a reference. For the code below, I need the 4th line to make Position work (Position is a property of a base class)

```
    Vector2 position = Position;
    position.x = Mathf.Clamp(Position.x, 0, mScreenSize.x);
    position.y = Mathf.Clamp(Position.y, 0, mScreenSize.y);
    Position = position; //This line is required to clamp the position into Position
```

Comment: It depends on the object. `Vector2` is a struct, so it will be returned by value (a copy). Other classes (objects) are reference types and will be returned by reference.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251608/are-structs-pass-by-value). Properties are no different.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type you are returning.  Properties are no different from other mechanisims.

If it is a value type, then it's a copy, if it is a reference type, then it's a reference.