# Why can't stack be copied from another one if I do it in a method?

Tags: c#, oop, reference, stack

`Stack<T>` is a class, so it is a reference type. It is possible to pass stack in functions without ref flag and change it by `Push`, `Pop` etc. but when I try to make something like this:

```
static void copyingStructs(Stack<MyStruct> stackSource, Stack<MyStruct> stackCopy)
{
    stackCopy = stackSource;
}
```

It doesn't work, in main function copied stack stays the same. I thought that it is because the value type struct, but the problem remains with stack of classes.
Of course I can use ref flag but I have a habit that if I don't know how something work in details I can't continue studying

Comment: This is completely unrelated to value vs reference types. The behaviour is the same in both cases because [C# always passes by value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9251645/1968). If you want to reassign a parameter inside a method, you need to pass it as `ref` or `out`. Of course doing so will *not* copy the data inside the stack.

Comment: There's a difference between "pass a reference by value" and "pass (anything) by reference". See http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: thank you for your aswers

Comment: In addition to the other comments here, I noted this sentence, "It doesn't work, in main function copied stack stays the same.", what **exactly** does this mean? What behavior did you expect, that you didn't observe?

Comment: Lasse, I expected stackCopy to be changed as I use the function copyingStructs

Comment: @JonSkeet wow, I've just read your article, it is fantastic! idk the reason why pointers in c++ were much easier for me than passing reference by value in c#. I will definitely buy c# in depth, if I find it in Russia

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the original stackCopy from within the method, you should use the ref keyword like this:

```
static void copyingStructs(ref Stack<MyStruct> stackSource, ref Stack<MyStruct> stackCopy)
{
    stackCopy = stackSource;
}
```