# java.lang.Number doesn't implement "+" or any other operators?

Tags: java, numbers, operators, addition, implements

I'm creating a class which is supposed to be able to be used with an array of any type of number (float, int, etc), so here is one method I have:

```
// T extends Number
public synchronized T[] average() {
    Number[] ret = new Number[queue[0].length];
    for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
            ret[i] += queue[j][i]; // WTF ERROR?!
        }
        ret[i] /= size; // WTF ERROR?!
    }
    return (T[])ret;
}
```

Except this won't compile because "Number" doesn't implement the "+=" or "/=" operators. Event worse, java's Number class doesn't implement even the most basic operators like "+" or "-"! How can I make a method which returns the average of an array of Numbers if java won't let me compile it because it thinks that numbers can't be added?!?!

Comment: Java doesn't have overload operators like C++.  What it does have are methods.  java.lang.BigInteger, for instance, has a method called "add".

Comment: Welcome to Java, where operators are not functions. Also, you should educate yourself about [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) because generics in Java don't work at all like templates do in C++.

Comment: By the way, Number is abstract.  You won't even be able to instantiate it.

Comment: *Nothing* implements operators; they're language/syntactical constructs. Strings are special-cased with syntactical sugar.

Comment: @PaulTomblin with the single exception of `+` being able to concatenate strings

Comment: Another problem that nobody else pointed out is the last line. If a variable is an instance of X, you can't cast it to a subclass of X.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the way numbers work in Java. The `Number` class is the superclass of numeric wrapper classes (`Integer`, `Float`, etc.) useful for representing primitive types (`int`, `float`, etc.) as objects, but it does *not* work with the usual arithmetic operators.

If you intend to use the arithmetic operators, then use primitive types. If you need to build a "generic" method that works for all numeric data types, you have no choice but to build several overloaded versions of the same method, one for each data type, for example:

```
public  float[] average(float[][]  queue) {...}
public double[] average(double[][] queue) {...}
```

Also be aware that code like this *appears* to work for wrapper types:

```
Integer i = 0;
i += 1;
System.out.println(i);
```

... But under the hood, Java is automatically [boxing and unboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055/what-is-boxing-and-unboxing-and-what-are-the-trade-offs) the `Integer`, since the `+=` operator only works for primitive types. It works because we're explicitly indicating that the number is an `Integer`, but it won't work for a `Number`, since Java needs to know exactly *what* type of number it's dealing with for performing the boxing/unboxing.

Comment: In addition to not working with arithmetic operators, the Number API doesn't provide any methods for performing arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your numbers to primitive types, and then the arithmetic operators will work.  You will notice that `Number` does have `doubleValue`, `intValue`, etc....

or alternatively, you can convert to `BigDecimal`, and use the arithmetic methods *defined on that class* (not `+`,`-`, etc, but `add`, `multiply`, etc....).  This method will be more accurate (if you need the best accuracy, use `BigDecimal`) since floats and doubles only represent a discrete set of numeric values.   Keep in mind that BigDecimals are immutable, so you always need to assign the result of an operation to a reference.

Comment: If he is going to explicitly convert to `double`, `int`, etc, then why on Earth is he using a `Number` to begin with? I don't think this is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want

```
public synchronized average() {  
    double ret = new double[queue[0].length];  
    for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; ++i) {  
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {  
            ret[i] += queue[j][i];  
        }  
        ret[i] /= size;  
    }  
    return ret;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you can't. Arithmetic operators work only on primitive types (and thanks to autoboxing and autounboxing on their wrappers). You have to override the given method for all the primitive types that you require the method to work on, as is done in many JDK classes.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the arithmetic operators will only work on primitive types. The problem here is that Java has class representations of these primitive types, and the switch from one to another is generally implicit, via the feature known as [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html).

In this case you will need to implement methods for the types of arithmetic operations you need, possibly having to create [overloaded methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) for every possible numeric type passed in for every operation.

Answer (score 0):

Since every possible `byte`, `short`, `char`, `int`, `float`, `double` can be represented as a `double` its is much more efficient (as its a primitive instead of any object) and simpler to use `double` instead of `Number`  You would need specific types if you need `long` accurately or BigDecimal or BigInteger.

Comment: @KennethNoland Can you give an example of a value of these types which cannot be stored in a double without losing precision?  double has at least 53 bits of precision which is more than enough to store any of these types.