# Abstract class with default value

Tags: java, abstract-class, abstract, default-value

I am trying to define a abstract Range class which will serve as the base implementation of a number of range classes. The intended use is irrelevant for this question, but so far I have:

```java
/**
 * Abstract generic utility class for handling ranges
 */
public abstract class Range<T extends Number> {

  // Variables to hold the range configuration
  private T start;
  private T stop;
  private T step;

  /**
   * Constructs a range by defining it's limits and step size.
   *
   * @param start The beginning of the range.
   * @param stop The end of the range.
   * @param step The stepping
   */
  public Range(T start, T stop, T step) {
    this.start = start;
    this.stop = stop;
    this.step = step;
  }
}
```

Now I want to add a constructor with that only takes `start` and `stop`, and sets a default step value of `1`, no matter what implementation of `Number` `T` is (e.g. if `T` is `Integer` `[one]` would have the value `1`, and if `T` is `Long` `[one]` would have the value `1L`, and so on). I would like something like:

```java
protected Range(T start, T stop) {
  this(start, stop, [one]);
}
```

but I can't figure out how so set the value of `[one]`. Since Java is still fairly new to me, I have tried with:

```java
private static final T one = 1;
```

which doesn't work because `T` is obviously defined in the instantiation of `Range.this`. Also I have tried:

```java
protected static abstract T getOne();
```

which also doesn't work because `T` is defined in the instantiation of `Range.this` plus `static` and `abstract` don't work together.

I need some way for extending classes to be forced to define the value of `[one]` no matter what implementation of `Number` `Range` is implemented for.

Ultimately I would also like to set a zero value as default start, such that I get a constructor that looks like this:

```java
protected Range(T stop) {
  this([zero], stop, [one]);
}
```

Comment: I'm nto sure Number is the right superclass to use. There is interesting question on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721390/how-to-add-two-java-lang-numbers - I mean even if you figure this out, how would you add the step to start to iterate over the range?

Comment: `this(start, stop, (T) (new Integer(1)));`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One solution would be to ask the subclasses for the default step to use:

```
public abstract class Range<T extends Number> {

    private T start;
    private T stop;
    private T step;

    public Range(T start, T stop, T step) {
        this.start = start;
        this.stop = stop;
        this.step = step;
    }

    protected Range(T start, T stop) {
        this.start = start;
        this.stop = stop;
        this.step = getDefaultStep();
    }

    protected abstract T getDefaultStep();

}

public class IntegerRange extends Range<Integer> {

    public IntegerRange(Integer start, Integer stop, Integer step) {
        super(start, stop, step);
    }

    public IntegerRange(Integer start, Integer stop) {
        super(start, stop);
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer getDefaultStep() {
        return 1;
    }

}

public class DoubleRange extends Range<Double> {

    public DoubleRange(Double start, Double stop, Double step) {
        super(start, stop, step);
    }

    public DoubleRange(Double start, Double stop) {
        super(start, stop);
    }

    @Override
    protected Double getDefaultStep() {
        return 1d;
    }

}
```

Comment: Boom! +1 for the quick answer.

Comment: I second that, although that every implementing class has to provide a default step regardless if it doesn't even use the short constructor.

Comment: You cannot do that. `Range.getDefaultStep` cannot be called before `Range` has been instanciated, and thus you cannot use it in the constructor.

Comment: Sorry, I just tried is the way you write it. I used `this(start, stop, getOne());` before which doesn't work.

Comment: @beruic Yes, that's why the 2-arg constructor can't call the 3-arg one. You have to explicitly set the members in the 2-arg one too, as I provided.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this implementation:

```
protected Range(T start, T stop) {
  this(start, stop, (T) (new Integer(1)));
}
```

Comment: Can `Integer` be cast to the other subclasses of `Number` like `Double`?

Comment: Yes; it could be converted.

Comment: Huh, that's interesting... Why would that cast succeed when an explicit cast like `Double d = (Double) new Integer(1);` not even compile?

Comment: I've tested my suggestion for `Range<Double>`, `Range<Byte>` and `Range<Long>`; they do work

Comment: Intriguing. I might consider it, but for now I will go with the methods. I have a feeling that implementing them for each type, and making them singleton will increase performance.

Answer (score 2):

You will run into another problems ... but here is your number 1:

```
Number ONE = new Number() {
    @Override
    public int intValue() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public long longValue() {
        return 1L;
    }

    @Override
    public float floatValue() {
        return 1.0f;
    }

    @Override
    public double doubleValue() {
        return 1.0;
    }

    @Override
    public byte byteValue() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public short shortValue() {
        return 1;
    }
};
```

Comment: Care to elaborate on the other problems? :)

Comment: It would be interesting to see how you will iterate over the range in generic way, I mean adding the `step` to the `start` and comapre it with `stop`. You can require the subclasses to provide you with `compare(T,T)`, `add(T,T)` etc. but it doesn't look nice IMHO :) On the other hand I don't see better solution ...

Comment: You can solve the comparable problem with Range<T extends Number & Comparable>, the arithmetic operations will be still painful

Comment: Lat comment, I promise :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957990/java-lang-number-doesnt-implement-or-any-other-operators