# How to set value object by reference

Tags: javascript, object

I want to set value `3` to `a.b` by reference to object a.

example:

```
var a ={};
a.a =1;
a.b =2;
var x = a.b;
alert (a.b);// show 2
x =3;
alert (a.b); // I want to see in this line 3 instead 2.
```

Many thanks

How I can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have pointers in JavaScript so you can't simply do that.

What you usually do to "replace" pointers in JavaScript is use callbacks :

```
var a ={};
a.a =1;
a.b =2;
var x = a.b;
alert (a.b);// show 2
var f = function(v){ a.b=v};
f(3);
alert (a.b); // alerts 3
```

This callback can be passed to other functions and is probably what's the nearest from what you want in this language.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. Since `2` is a primitive, you don't have a reference to it, instead `x` actually has the value `3`.

What you can do is to provide a function that will modify the property of the parent object:

```
var a = {
   a: 1,
   b: 2,
   setB: function(value) {
      this.b = value;
   }
}

a.setB(3);
console.log(a.b);
```

I think this is cleaner.

To answer your edit, yes, sort of. It depends what you're doing. If you had the following:

```
var a = {
   a: {value: 1},
   b: {value: 2},
};

var x = a.b;
x = {value: 3};
```

Then `a.b` would still be `{value: 2}`, because all you have done is made `x` point to a different object. But realize that `x` points to `a.b`, which is an object, so instead, if you do `x.value = 3;`, `a.b` now has `{value: 3}`.

Comment: Would it be possible if objects were used instead of primitives? If not, that part seems a tad misleading/badly phrased.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass only objects by reference.

```
var a = {};
a.a = 1;
a.b = 2;
var x = a;
alert (a.b); // 2
x.b = 3;
alert (a.b); // 3
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dTzLQ/)

Answer (score 0):

one more example

```
 var a ={};
    a.a =1;
    a.b =2;
    var x =function(v){ a.b=v};
    alert (a.b);// show 2
    x(3);
    alert (a.b);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a situation where you want to pass a reference to a value, you could always use boxing. The reality is that your business case is going to determine what works best for you.

[What is boxing and unboxing and what are the trade offs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055/what-is-boxing-and-unboxing-and-what-are-the-trade-offs)

Here is a little untested pseudocode, but it should work for you.

You have a couple of options, considering the whole object as a reference, or just boxing on a single primitive value.

```
var c={}
c.a = null
c.b = null

//set the value of "c"
c = a;

//change the value of the reference
a.b = 100;

//now the reference has been update
alert( c.b );  // equals 100
```

OR if you just want the int boxed

```
var boxed_value = {}
boxed_value.total = 100;

var obj_a = {};
obj_a.value_a = boxed_value;

//obj_a.value_a.total = 100;


var obj_b = {};
obj_b.value = boxed_value;

//obj_b.value_a.total = 100
//obj_a.value_a.total = 100

boxed_value.total = 200;
obj_a.value.total = 300;
obj_b.value.total = 400;

//now all values have changed as they are referenced
```