# JavaScript Add Values to Multidimensional Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I am trying to add some values to a multidimensional array using a for loop. This is what I have created so far:

```
var test1 = [];
var test2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < top10.length; i++)
{
    test1[i] = i;
    test1[i][0] = top10[i][0];
    test1[i][1] = top10[i][1];
}
```

This is just returning an empty array. top10 is a multidimensional array which contains:

[image: top10 Array]

It can contain more data that's why I need a for loop. I am trying to create 2 multidimensional arrays "test1" and "test2" one will contain "Hinckley Train Station" and "4754" the other will contain "Hinckley Train Station" and "2274".

I can have multiple venues not just "Hinckley Train Station" "4754" "2274" I could also have "London City" "5000" "1000". This is why it is a for loop.

Comment: It would be useful to post a subset of the data in `top10` so we can fully replicate your code.

Comment: Returning? There's nothing returning anything there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could push a new array to the wanted parts

```js
var top10 = [
        ["Hinckley Train Station", "4754", "2274"],
        ["London City", "5000", "1000"]
    ],
    test1 = [],
    test2 = [],
    i;

for (i = 0; i < top10.length; i++) {
    test1.push([top10[i][0], top10[i][1]]);
    test2.push([top10[i][0], top10[i][2]]);
}

console.log(test1);
console.log(test2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I have done this but it doesn't create an array inside an array which is what I need

Comment: how the result different from the wanted one?

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
test1[i] = i;
```

You are assigning an integer to be the first element of the outer array. You don't have a 2d array, you have an array of integers

In the following lines:

```
test1[i][0] = top10[i][0];
test1[i][1] = top10[i][1];
```

You are assigning properties to an integer, which means [they are being boxed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055/what-is-boxing-and-unboxing-and-what-are-the-trade-offs) but the boxed value is thrown away.

It's hard to tell what you are trying to do, but the following is probably closer. You need to create a new inner array each time through the loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < top10.length; i++)
{
    test1[i] = [];
    test1[i][0] = top10[i][0];
    test1[i][1] = top10[i][1];
    // Maybe do something similar with test2
}
```